# Plone on Docker always starts from scratch

Tags: docker, plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to develope Plone project with Docker, i have used this [official image](https://github.com/plone/plone.docker/blob/master/5.2/5.2.0/debian/Dockerfile) of Plone 5.2.0, the images is built a run perfectly with:

```
$ docker build -t plone-5.2.0-official-img .
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -it plone-5.2.0-official-cntr
```

But the plone restarts each time i run the docker container asking to create the project from skratch.

[image]

Anybody could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask Plone questions in our forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, because `docker run` starts a new container, which doesn't have the state from your previous container.

You can use `docker start CONTAINER`, which will have the state from that `CONTAINER`'s setup
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/

A more common approach is to use `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose up -d`, which will, in most cases, reuse previous state.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a volume for data like:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -it -v plone-data:/data plone-5.2.0-official-cntr
```

The next time you'll run a new container it will re-use previous data.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps,

Volumes are the docker way to persist data. You can read it up over [here](https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-7-data-volumes-93073a1b5b72)

When running the container just add a -v option and specify your path to store your data.

```
$ docker run -p "port:port" -it -v "path"
```

Comment: How is this a different answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404480/3714940)?